# Numpy: convert an array to a triangular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I was looking for a built in method to convert an linear array to triangular matrix. As I failed in find one I am asking for help in implementing one.

Imagine an array like:

```
In [203]: dm
Out[203]: array([ 0.80487805,  0.90243902,  0.85365854, ...,  0.95121951,
                  0.90243902,  1.        ])

In [204]: dm.shape
Out[204]: (2211,)
```

And I would like to convert this array to a an triangular matrix or a symmetric rectangular matrix.

```
 In [205]: reshapedDm = dm.trian_reshape(67, 67)
```

How I would implement trian_reshape as function that returns an triangular matrix from 1-D array?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
>>> tri = np.zeros((67, 67))
>>> tri[np.triu_indices(67, 1)] = dm
```

See [doc for `triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) for details. To get a lower-triangular matrix, use `np.tril_indices` and set the offset to `-1` instead of `1`.