# How to create an upper triangular matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I need create upper triangular matrix given a set of values(the order is not importation). The matrix could be too large to input manually. `np.triu` only gives you the upper triangular of a existing matrix, not creating a new one.

I am doing some optimization to get the parameters of upper triangular cholesky root of covariance matrix. My parameters are upper triangular cholesky roots of some covariance matrix. To initializing, I need to put the parameter values in the position of upper triangular.

```
array([[ a,  b,  c],
       [ 0,  d,  e],
       [ 0,  0,  f]])
```

Comment: Sorry, what output are you hoping for?  [From your [1,2,3],...[10,11,12] input, I mean.]

Comment: @DSM, I have edited the question.

Comment: I tend to make an empty matrix and fill it using the indices, as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055493/numpy-convert-an-array-to-a-triangular-matrix).  Would that work?

Comment: @DSM, it seems working. Let me try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question, so I didn't want to leave this one without an answer. Based on the suggestions by @DSM I created the function below:

```
import numpy as np

def create_upper_matrix(values, size):
    upper = np.zeros((size, size))
    upper[np.triu_indices(3, 0)] = values
    return(upper)

c = create_upper_matrix([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
print(c)
```

This could be improved by adding functionality that infers the size of the required matrix from the data, but for now it relies on the user providing that information.