# Transforming a list containing the elements below the diagonal of a matrix into a full matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, matrix-transform

I want to create a full-fledged matrix from a list of the elements that are below the diagonal. The following list contains the elements below the diagonal:
[image]

And this would be the desired output:

[image]

Up until this point, I tried to make this work with normal sintax in python by implementing the following code:

```
list_similarities = [1,0.1,0.6,0.4,1,0.1,0.2,1,0.7,1]

the_range = range(0,4)

list_of_lists = []
counter_element = 0
counter = -1
for element in the_range:
    counter += 1
    counter_element += len(the_range)-element
    intermediary = (len(the_range)-element)
    first_element = counter_element-intermediary
    line_list = list_similarities[first_element:counter_element]
    # counter = 0, then no need to add an additional element
    # print(line_list)
    if counter == 0:
        "do nothing"
    elif counter >0:
        for item in range(0,element):
            from_list_to_add = list_of_lists[item]
            element_to_add = from_list_to_add[item+1]
            line_list.insert(0,element_to_add)
    print(line_list)
    list_of_lists.append(line_list.copy())
    # print("final lists:", list_of_lists)


# print(counter_element)
print("final lists:", list_of_lists)
```

However, the output is the following:

> final lists: [[1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.4], [0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.2], [0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.7], [0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 1]]

It does the first 2 lists, which represent the 2 rows from the matrix, but will not do the last 2 because of the way my code works and so far I don't know a solution for that..

This is due to the fact that my counter will make the list go out of range. I looked at a lot of posts on the stack overflow, but I cannot find something that would work in my situation. If you can point me towards a similar example it would be perfect.

Thank you for your time and suggestions!

**UPDATE :**
My question is not a duplicate of [Numpy: convert an array to a triangular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055493/numpy-convert-an-array-to-a-triangular-matrix) because I do not want to create a matrix where my values from the array are part of just the lower triangular matrix, but rather they are also in the upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy: convert an array to a triangular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055493/numpy-convert-an-array-to-a-triangular-matrix)

Comment: @Andrian see my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: @seralouk thank you for taking the time to come up with a solution! It works as expected :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) and [`numpy.tril_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html). I have guided each step with comments. The key is to first find the upper right indices, assign the value from the list, then make the matrix symmetric.

```
import numpy as np

n = 4
l = [1,0.1,0.6,0.4,1,0.1,0.2,1,0.7,1]

a = np.zeros((n,n)) # Initialize nxn matrix
triu = np.triu_indices(n) # Find upper right indices of a triangular nxn matrix
tril = np.tril_indices(n, -1) # Find lower left indices of a triangular nxn matrix
a[triu] = l # Assign list values to upper right matrix
a[tril] = a.T[tril] # Make the matrix symmetric

print(a)
```

Output

```
[[1.  0.1 0.6 0.4]
 [0.1 1.  0.1 0.2]
 [0.6 0.1 1.  0.7]
 [0.4 0.2 0.7 1. ]]
```

Comment: i posted a slightly different and shorter answer

Comment: @Adrian, I have simplified my answer, which works too and it's cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

### Its very simple using `numpy.triu_indices_from`.

***Use this:***

```
import numpy as np

list_similarities = [1,0.1,0.6,0.4,1,0.1,0.2,1,0.7,1]
n = 4

Full_matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
inds = np.triu_indices_from(Full_matrix, k = 0)
# use [:] to copy the list and avoid any problem if the initial list is further needed
Full_matrix[inds] = list_similarities[:]
Full_matrix[(inds[1], inds[0])] = list_similarities[:]
```

***Results***

```
array([[1. , 0.1, 0.6, 0.4],
       [0.1, 1. , 0.1, 0.2],
       [0.6, 0.1, 1. , 0.7],
       [0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 1. ]])
```

P.S: More details about the reason I copy the list using `list_similarities[:]` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/5025009)

Comment: I am creating a copy of the list. and this is the best way to do it. There is a huge difference between `list_similarities = list_similarities[:]` and `list_similarities = list_similarities`. This is the safiest way